# Divide slice array in to two

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a dynamic slice array and I want to divide them in to two for example:

```
["21:35 DXB", "23:40 HBE"]<br/>
["14:30 DXB", "16:35 HBE"]<br/>
["04:10 HBE", "09:10 DXB"]<br/>
["01:45 HBE", "06:50 DXB"]<br/>
["11:10 HBE", "16:15 DXB"]<br/>
["18:25 HBE", "23:35 DXB"]
```

I want the first array from DXB to HBE :

```
["21:35 DXB", "23:40 HBE"]<br/>
["14:30 DXB", "16:35 HBE"]<br/>
```

The second array from HBE to DXB :

```
["04:10 HBE", "09:10 DXB"]<br/>
["01:45 HBE", "06:50 DXB"]<br/>
["11:10 HBE", "16:15 DXB"]<br/>
["18:25 HBE", "23:35 DXB"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate through your array and then add them into different arrays:

```
let arr = [["21:35 DXB", "23:40 HBE"], ["14:30 DXB", "16:35 HBE"],["04:10 HBE", "09:10 DXB"],["01:45 HBE", "06:50 DXB"], ["11:10 HBE", "16:15 DXB"], ["18:25 HBE", "23:35 DXB"]]

var arrDXB = [[String]]()
var arrHBE = [[String]]()


for item in arr{
    if item[0].rangeOfString("DXB") != nil {
        arrDXB.append(item)
    }
    else{
        arrHBE.append(item)
    }
}
```

`arrDXB` will be `[["21:35 DXB", "23:40 HBE"], ["14:30 DXB", "16:35 HBE"]]`
`arrHBE` will be `[["04:10 HBE", "09:10 DXB"], ["01:45 HBE", "06:50 DXB"], ["11:10 HBE", "16:15 DXB"], ["18:25 HBE", "23:35 DXB"]]`